# linux floating point _control87 replacement

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, floating-point

I am working through a port of some code (from Windows to Linux), mostly in an attempt to learn more about programming in c++ on Linux.

I've come across a function containing this:

```
_clear87();

_control87(_PC_24, MCW_PC);
_control87(_RC_CHOP, MCW_RC);
_24 = getFPUsw(); // 24, chop
_control87(_RC_NEAR, MCW_RC);
_24r = getFPUsw(); // 24, rounding

_control87(_PC_53, MCW_PC);
_control87(_RC_CHOP, MCW_RC);
_53 = getFPUsw(); // 53, chop
_control87(_RC_NEAR, MCW_RC);
_53r = getFPUsw(); // 53, rounding

_control87(_PC_64, MCW_PC);
_control87(_RC_CHOP, MCW_RC);
_64 = getFPUsw(); // 64, chop
_control87(_RC_NEAR, MCW_RC);
_64r = getFPUsw(); // 64, rounding
```

From what I can tell. The _control87 and _clear87 are Windows only and are used to change the FPU modes for floating point calculations and the like. Defined on windows in `<float.h>`

The equivalent on Linux seems to be along the lines of the functions in `#include <cfenv>`

I am unsure of what the equivalent of these _control87 functions is and am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction here.

Comment: My memory is hazy, but I think you want to look at the [fpu_control.h header file](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/fpu_005fcontrol_002eh.html) to manipulate the precision control bits of the x87 FPU control word.

Comment: Thanks. That looks more like what I need.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it seems so that fenv.h is platform independent.
Example:
http://howtounix.info/man/FreeBSD/man3/fenv.3

Using .NET, this might also work:

```
Word uSaved8087CW = System::Default8087CW;
...
//for example:
System::Set8087CW(0x133f); // Disable all fpu exceptions.
//calculations
...
System::Set8087CW( uSaved8087CW );
```